# Perl TK Gui freezes

Tags: multithreading, perl, user-interface

I have a perl tk application where in i create many objects and update the perl tk gui display with information in objects.I need to add large number of jobs(say 30k) in the tree in the gui.If i add all jobs in one go,the gui freezes.

Below is the code snippet:

```
sub Importjobs
{

  #================= start creation of objects=============================
  my JobList $self = shift;
  my $exportedJobList = shift;
  # third parameter whether to clear the list
  $self->clear () unless shift;
  my $noOfProcsToBeAdded = shift || 3000;



 my $cellCollection = Tasks::CellCollection::instance ();
  my $calcActionsPathHash = $cellCollection->caPathCAHash ();
  my $collectionCellNames = $cellCollection->allCellNames ();

  my @importedJobs = ();
  # if the given job list is empty, add import job list to it
  push @{$self->_importJobList()}, @$exportedJobList;
  $exportedJobList = [];
  # do not import new jobs if the previous jobs are still being created
  foreach my $taskGenJob(@{$self->getTaskGenJobObjs()}) {
    goto FINISH if TaskGenJobState::CREATE == $taskGenJob->state();
  }
  # now get each job and add it into the imported jobs till the noOfJobs exceeds $noOfJobsToBeAdded
  while(my $jobDescription = shift @{$self->_importJobList()}) {
    my $taskInstantiation = $jobDescription->{'taskInstantiation'};
    my $caPath     = $taskInstantiation->{'calcActionPath'};
    my $errMsgPrefix = 'Error importing ' . join ('-', $task, $command, $method, $caPath);
    my @calcActionList;
    if(defined $caPath) {
      my $calcAction = $calcActionsPathHash->{ $caPath };
      unless($calcAction) {
        my $errMsg = $errMsgPrefix . ": the calcAction is not defined within the current CellCollection : " . $caPath;
        $logger4Perl -> error ($errMsg);
        next;
      }
      push @calcActionList, $calcAction;
    } else {
      my @mList;
      if(not defined $method) {
        push @mList, @{$task->getMethods(cellCollection => $cellCollection, command => $command)};
        $method = join(' ', @mList);
      } elsif($method eq $task_desc::default_method) {
        @mList = ($task_desc::default_method);
      } else {
        @mList = sort (grep { $_ } split(/\s+|__/, $method));
      }
      foreach my $m (@mList) {
        push(@calcActionList,  @{$cellCollection->findCalcActions($task, $command, $m)});
      }
    }
    foreach my $calcAction(@calcActionList) {
       my TaskGenJob $job = TaskGenJob->new ();
      $logger4Perl->info ("Adding $caPath");
      push (@importedJobs, $job);
      my $noOfProcsBeingAdded = $job->calculateNoOfJobExecObjs();
      $noOfProcsToBeAdded -= $noOfProcsBeingAdded;
    }
    last if 1 > $noOfProcsToBeAdded;
  }
  #================= End creation of objects=============================

  #Below function updates the GUI display
    $self->addJobs (\@importedJobs);  

  #================= Mechanism which am using so that GUI will be active after certain time limit=============================
  FINISH:
  if(@{$self->_importJobList()}) {
    $self->parentDlg()->parentWnd()->after(60000,
      sub {
        $GuiTasksAppl::mainDlg->Disable();
        $self->importJobList([], 'noclear', 200);
        $GuiTasksAppl::mainDlg->Enable();
      });
  }
}
```

Currently the way am doing it is to add say 3000 jobs using $noOfProcsToBeAdded variable and stay idle for some time and repeat the process after some time.During this idle process,there is different process which processes the jobs in GUI.

can someone propose a better approach than this ???
Expecting ideas on threading ,shared memory.

Comment: Can you `$mw->update` or `$mw->idletasks` while your adding jobs?  See this Perl Monks explanation: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=574002

Answer (score 1):

First, if the GUI freezes (and never unfreezes) during your large 30k update then you might have found a Tk bug since that shouldn't happen.  However, if its merely ***unresponsive*** for a period of time, then it make sense to mitigate the delay.

In the past, i've used either Tk::repeat() or Tk::after() to drive my UI update routine.  The user interface doesn't typically need to be updated at a high rate, so every few hundred milliseconds can be a reasonable delay.  The determining factor is largely determined by how responsive of an interface you need.  Then during the job import step: append references to a list for the UI update routine and then periodically call $MW->update().  The update routine doesn't necessarily need to process the full list during each call but you don't want the processing to get too far behind.

I'd also recommend some visual indicator to identify that the update is still in-progress.

If ImportJobs is computationally expensive, obviously one could perform multi-process / multi-threading tricks to exploit multiple processors on the system.  But that'll add a bit of complexity and testing effort.